# Atribuir view existente a uma controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma view q está atribuída a uma controller. Tudo estava nessa controller. Agora decidimos criar uma controller para cada situação nossa aqui. Só que eu não gostaria de criar uma nova view, pois uma já existe. Essa view se chama Hotel. Criei uma controller chamada Hotel e uma Action com o mesmo nome. Quero atribuir essa Action a essa view. Não posso colocar na Action assim: return View(Hotel); porque o return dessa action é um parâmetro passado para a Action, que está assim: return View(_package); Se der um Add view, vai criar uma nova. Tem como fazer o que gostaria? No aguardo.

Answer (score 2):

Só colocar a sua *View* no diretório `Shared`. Assim todos os *Controllers* poderão chamar a *View* Hotel da seguinte forma:

```
return View("Hotel", _package);
```